# How to determine the current delimiter in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there a way to determine the current delimiter in MySQL Workbench?

`status` (or `\s`) works only on the command line client, how to do the same in Workbench?

Comment: Same question :D Waiting for new answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter is a dynamic thing. There's no global state which holds a "current delimiter". Instead each scripts (on every execution) starts out with the default delimiter (the semicolon) and switches it only if the script says so.